# Can I push to git and force a maximum pack size?

Tags: git, github

I'm pushing a very large repository to GitHub, and I'm getting an error saying that the pack exceeds the maximum allowed size:

```
git push
Counting objects: 2072164, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (731293/731293), done.
fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size2.00 GiB | 118 KiB/s      
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
```

Is there a way to force a maximum pack size when pushing? I've tried `git repack --max-pack-size=1g -d -f -F -a` before pushing. I've also tried `git config pack.packSizeLimit 1g`. Is there another way?

Comment: As a workaround, you could push a smaller part of the repository first, and thus do your big push in parts. You could do this for example by pushing an old revision of your branch.

Comment: How big are the pack files now?

Comment: @dgnorton I never managed to fix the problem. I worked around it instead. This is a fork of a project. I can push to a large fork, but I can't upload my own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  You cannot change the pack size for a push directly.

See my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125862/github-remote-push-pack-size-exceeded) for an explanation.