# How To Upload Really Large Project To Github With Multiple Files

Tags: git, github

I got a project. A client wants her prestashop site uploaded to github.

I started adding and committing one folder at a time. At a certain point, github started returning an error.

How would you solve this issue of uploading a site with thousands, if not tens of thousands of files to github?

I have Windows.

Edit:

Hi there. I added some files. I was adding bit by bit. Then what happened was I got greedy and added too many files at once. Now, no matter what I try, I keep getting this error. How can I fix this?

```
$ git push
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/guestaccount/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enumerating objects: 35931, done.
Counting objects: 100% (35931/35931), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (35856/35856), done.
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To github.com:(mygithubid)/(repo).git
 ! [remote rejected]   main -> main (failed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:(mygithubid)/(repo).git'
```

I am using Visual Studio Code and git bash to upload.

Comment: Since this seems to be a commercial enterprise, obtain (pay for) GitHub support and use GitHub support...? (Also: why tag this with [tag:gitlab] if you're on GitHub rather than GitLab?)

Comment: We'd need to know the error to help, but I have a guess. Git and Github have no trouble with tens of thousands of files, you can and should add them all at once (git add .) in the initial "import existing project into Git" commit. Though you will want to make sure you're not uploading any customer information or secrets. What it does have a problem with is very large files. See [Working with large files](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files) and [Versioning large files](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files).

Comment: I have clarified my question. The error is posted above. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: See [Git - pack exceeds maximum allowed size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24704844/1256452), which links in turn to [Github remote push pack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15125862/1256452). Note, however, that GitHub also place a limit on repository size unless you get a paid account there.

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded a project having a large amount of files using GitHub desktop. Create your repository through the app or from the website. Clone it and upload your code through it.