# Error posting remote branch in git (remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size)

Tags: git, github

I need help, I have problem publishing the git repository, I'm trying to push with git bash, but I got the error below, I tried eGit too
did not work. Initially, I thought I might be setting LF because, by checking in git, it would display the message "LF will be replaced
by CRLF" so it could be creating duplicate file.So I disabled this with the command: git config --global core.autocrlf false, built the project, made a
git pull with my remote branch in the repository and tried git push again but the error persists.

```
$ git push origin feature/menu-itens-aspWeb
Enumerating objects: 783, done.
Counting objects: 100% (587/587), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (225/225), done.
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
Writing objects: 100% (362/362), 102.88 MiB | 3.95 MiB/s, done.
Total 362 (delta 168), reused 1 (delta 1)
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: This might help https://github.community/t5/Support-Protips/Working-with-large-files-and-repositories/ba-p/9343

Comment: Consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64565533/). Also, this thread looks to be a duplicate of [Github remote push pack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125862/github-remote-push-pack-size-exceeded)