# Git push fails for large number of commits

Tags: git, github, push, large-files, git-push

Similar to:

[Github remote push pack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125862/github-remote-push-pack-size-exceeded)

Failure message:

```
Pushing efb55fab0352e4fff42129d00b642e908e9d09c1...
Counting objects: 617706, done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (368204/368204), done.
Writing objects:  36% (222375/617706), 1.79 GiB | 278.60 MiB/s     

remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Failed sending data to the peer
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (617706/617706), 4.37 GiB | 185.36 MiB/s, done.
Total 617706 (delta 218614), reused 617467 (delta 218375)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
Counting objects: 617709, done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (368206/368206), done.
Writing objects:  36% (222376/617709), 1.83 GiB | 392.11 MiB/s
```

Context:

1. Working on a fork  of kiwi (https://github.com/kiwibrowser/src)
2. Created a script from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51468389/1079483
3. Added token to url for convenience:

   $ git remote set-url origin https://:@github.com/path/to/repo.git
4. Ran push; after a few hours the above error was thrown?

Comment: `remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size` is the key line: GitHub set a limit on how big a push you can do (along with limits on individual file sizes and other limits). When you get this, your only option is to break your push into smaller pieces, pushing each one as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GitHub.com the size limit is 100MB
https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files/conditions-for-large-files

If you have Github Enterprise Server you can change the size limit if you have the permissions to do so.
https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files/conditions-for-large-files

If some of these files are binary files, you could use Git LFS?