# remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size

Tags: gitlab, repository, git-lfs

While pushing local repo to remote(gitlab), I am getting the below error -

[image]

While the local repository size turns out to be very small as below -

[image]

Tried a few troubleshooting steps, using lfs, deleting git history. The error does not seem to be resolved. Can anyone suggest where the step is going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github remote push pack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125862/github-remote-push-pack-size-exceeded)

Comment: @sytech - lfs solved.
Resolved - 
find -x . -path ./.git -prune -o -type f -size +5M -exec git lfs track {} +

Answer (score 2):

Resolved -
find -x . -path ./.git -prune -o -type f -size +5M -exec git lfs track {} +